# Inner product of states in Q#

Tags: q#

I have a state $|x\rangle$ and I want to get the expected result when measuring observable $A$ (i.e. get the result of $\langle x| A | x \rangle$). In my case $A$ can be any of the Pauli gates. Does anyone know how to do this in `Q#`? There doesn't seem to be an inner product function in the libraries.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're really asking about how to *measure* in a given Pauli basis. (I'm assuming for simplicity that you are working with only a single qubit, but the below is generalizable to multiple qubits as well.)

Q# has a [Measure operation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.measure) which performs a measurement in a given Pauli basis. For example, if you have a `Qubit` object `q` in some state $|\psi\rangle$ and you want to measure it in the $X$ basis, you can write:

```
   let result = Measure([PauliX], [q]);
```

Here `result` will be either `Zero` or `One`. If you want to then estimate the expectation value of the measurement, you would need to repeat your full operation (including whatever you did to prepare your qubit in the state $|\psi\rangle$) many times and take an average of the measurement results.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your reply! I tried to measure a qubit which is in the |0> state in the Pauli X basis, but I get an expected value of around 0.5, like if the qubit was in superposition. Shouldn't I get expected value of 0 as that is the result of <0|X|0> ? In the documentation it seems like a Hadamard is applied when trying to measure in the Pauli X basis, so that would explain why I get 0.5, but I don't get why would you apply an H gate? (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/concepts/pauli-measurements)

Comment: If your qubit is in the |0⟩ state, that is a Pauli-Z basis state. In terms of Pauli-X basis states, |0⟩ = (|+⟩ + |-⟩)/sqrt(2), so it is actually in superposition with respect to that basis. When measuring a state in the Pauli-X basis, a `Zero` result corresponds to |+⟩ and a `One` result corresponds to |-⟩. So it's correct that measuring the state |0⟩ in the Pauli-X basis will give equal probabilities of `Zero` and `One`. On the other hand, if you measure |0⟩ in the Pauli-Z basis, you should get `Zero` with 100% probability.

Comment: I understand now, thanks a lot for the clear explanation!